# Event on Visual Studio project creation

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-addins, envdte, visual-studio-templates

I want to add functionality when the user creates project \ solution in Visual Studio 2010\2012. i.e. I need to perform C# code when a new project is created.

I googled a lot but didn't find any event which is fired on\after project creation.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: **I need to perform C# code**


what u mean by this? can you please explain in details. Do you mean you want to run C# cmd/u want to insert predefine C# code in project/you wan to trigger some C# exe or what?

Comment: I have C# Code which using EnvDTE etc, and I want to add this as function or something else that will be called when the project is created.

Comment: I am not sure, but try if this can help u out. [click this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36219/Exploring-EnvDTE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and thanks to article mentioned by @Joe Steele, I've managed to hook up the [`CommandEvents.AfterExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.commandeventsclass.afterexecute.aspx) event, responsible for project creation:

```
DTE application = this.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
string guidVSStd97 = "{5efc7975-14bc-11cf-9b2b-00aa00573819}".ToUpper();
int cmdidNewProject = 216;

this.createCmd = application.Events.CommandEvents[guidVSStd97, cmdidNewProject];
this.createCmd.AfterExecute += this.command_AfterExecute;
```

And this is how the delegate looks like:

```
void command_AfterExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut)
{
    // place your code here
}
```

**Notes**:

1. Probably the most difficult part was to find the right `guid` and `commandId`, but [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826040.aspx) was of help.
2. Sometimes, during debugging, event didn't fire at all, which made me baffled, but thankfully I've stumbled across this piece of advise:

> The SolutionEvents object can go out of scope and be garbage collected before the solution is closed. To retain a reference to this object, declare a private variable in the class in which you implement the solution event handlers.[<sup>Source</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionevents.aspx)

Thus introduction of private variable solved the issue:

```
private CommandEvents createCmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a template project that has your code in it. So other users can use your template instead of the default VS templates.

Comment: I tried it before, but VS2010 C++ template project supports just javascript code, and I want to perform C# code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to catch an interactive project creation (i.e. the user selected "New -> Project" from the menu) you should be able to just hook the menu event. However Visual Studio doesn't provide those events directly.

[This post from Microsoft support talks about getting around that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555393).
Yes -- the article is very old, but I believe is still accurate. Please correct me if I am wrong. It has been a *long* time since I created a VS extension. The event friendly name is probably something like "New.Project". You will have to figure out the GUID and ID.

If you have not created a Visual Studio extension before, [this is a good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx).

If you are trying to catch non-interactive project creation -- there are a lot more places to hook. Someone wiser than I will have to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that events are only fired at runtime. And since the creation of a project doesn't happen in runtime there are no events for this.

The only way I can think of is checking the size of the folder containing all projects and see if it changed, then fire your C# code

Comment: That way can work theoretical, but there are 3 problems: One, I have just VS Add-In, I can't checking the size of user's folder all the time (Which event can I perform that?) . The second one- the user can add his project in any location in his computer, so I don't have a specific folder to check. The third, when I detect size changing, how can I know which project added? and maybe the user added another files?